Error running project comming from github
how to run a project comming from  repository
!!  Warning: require(C:\Users\SYNS-MANAGER\pmanalysis\vendor\composer/../symfony/var-dumper/Resources/functions/dump.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\SYNS-MANAGER\pmanalysis\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 41
!!
!!  Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'C:\Users\SYNS-MANAGER\pmanalysis\vendor\composer/../symfony/var-dumper/Resources/functions/dump.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Users\SYNS-MANAGER\pmanalysis\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php:41
!!  Stack trace:
!!  #0 C:\Users\SYNS-MANAGER\pmanalysis\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php(45): {closure}('667aeda72477189...', 'C:\Users\SYNS-M...')
!!  #1 C:\Users\SYNS-MANAGER\pmanalysis\vendor\autoload.php(25): ComposerAutoloaderInit8201ee3e7ef0d800a8c33ed776337655::getLoader()
!!  #2 C:\Users\SYNS-MANAGER\pmanalysis\vendor\autoload_runtime.php(5): require_once('C:\Users\SYNS-M...')
!!  #3 C:\Users\SYNS-MANAGER\pmanalysis\bin\console(15): require_once('C:\Users\SYNS-M...')
!!  #4 {main}
!!    thrown in C:\Users\SYNS-MANAGER\pmanalysis\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 41
!!  PHP Warning:  require(C:\Users\SYNS-MANAGER\pmanalysis\vendor\composer/../symfony/var-dumper/Resources/functions/dump.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\SYNS-MANAGER\pmanalysis\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 41
!!  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'C:\Users\SYNS-MANAGER\pmanalysis\vendor\composer/../symfony/var-dumper/Resources/functions/dump.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Users\SYNS-MANAGER\pmanalysis\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php:41
!!  Stack trace:
!!  #0 C:\Users\SYNS-MANAGER\pmanalysis\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php(45): {closure}('667aeda72477189...', 'C:\Users\SYNS-M...')
!!  #1 C:\Users\SYNS-MANAGER\pmanalysis\vendor\autoload.php(25): ComposerAutoloaderInit8201ee3e7ef0d800a8c33ed776337655::getLoader()
!!  #2 C:\Users\SYNS-MANAGER\pmanalysis\vendor\autoload_runtime.php(5): require_once('C:\Users\SYNS-M...')
!!  #3 C:\Users\SYNS-MANAGER\pmanalysis\bin\console(15): require_once('C:\Users\SYNS-M...')
!!  #4 {main}
!!    thrown in C:\Users\SYNS-MANAGER\pmanalysis\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 41
!!
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-install-cmd
PS C:\Users\SYNS-MANAGER\pmanalysis> php bin/console cache:clear
PHP Warning:  require(C:\Users\SYNS-MANAGER\pmanalysis\vendor\composer/../symfony/var-dumper/Resources/functions/dump.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\SYNS-MANAGER\pmanalysis\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 41
Warning: require(C:\Users\SYNS-MANAGER\pmanalysis\vendor\composer/../symfony/var-dumper/Resources/functions/dump.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\SYNS-MANAGER\pmanalysis\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 41
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'C:\Users\SYNS-MANAGER\pmanalysis\vendor\composer/../symfony/var-dumper/Resources/functions/dump.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Users\SYNS-MANAGER\pmanalysis\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php:41
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Users\SYNS-MANAGER\pmanalysis\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php(45): {closure}('667aeda72477189...', 'C:\Users\SYNS-M...')
#1 C:\Users\SYNS-MANAGER\pmanalysis\vendor\autoload.php(25): ComposerAutoloaderInit8201ee3e7ef0d800a8c33ed776337655::getLoader()
#2 C:\Users\SYNS-MANAGER\pmanalysis\vendor\autoload_runtime.php(5): require_once('C:\Users\SYNS-M...')
#3 C:\Users\SYNS-MANAGER\pmanalysis\bin\console(15): require_once('C:\Users\SYNS-M...')
#4 {main}
thrown in C:\Users\SYNS-MANAGER\pmanalysis\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 41
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'C:\Users\SYNS-MANAGER\pmanalysis\vendor\composer/../symfony/var-dumper/Resources/functions/dump.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Users\SYNS-MANAGER\pmanalysis\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php:41
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Users\SYNS-MANAGER\pmanalysis\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php(45): {closure}('667aeda72477189...', 'C:\Users\SYNS-M...')
#1 C:\Users\SYNS-MANAGER\pmanalysis\vendor\autoload.php(25): ComposerAutoloaderInit8201ee3e7ef0d800a8c33ed776337655::getLoader()
#2 C:\Users\SYNS-MANAGER\pmanalysis\vendor\autoload_runtime.php(5): require_once('C:\Users\SYNS-M...')
#3 C:\Users\SYNS-MANAGER\pmanalysis\bin\console(15): require_once('C:\Users\SYNS-M...')
#4 {main}
thrown in C:\Users\SYNS-MANAGER\pmanalysis\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 41
after installing dependencies
composer install
how to solve it?
